# PHP money format add decimal and comma when needed

Tags: php, currency, number-formatting, money-format

How do I turn this number **247936** into this **$2,479.36** using php?

I tried several options such as:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', '247936'); // OUTPUT: USD 247,936.00
```

I also tried this

```
echo number_format(247936, 2);  // echos '247,936.00'
```

I even tried this but it didn't work as well

```
echo number_format(247936, 2,'.', ','); // echos 247,936.00
```

Comment: So your value is in cents right?

Comment: I believe so yes. the last two numbers are the cents.

Comment: `money_format()` should not be used because it was deprecated in PHP7.4 and removed in PHP8 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like your variable is in cents, so divide it by 100

```
echo number_format((247936 / 100), 2, '.', ',');
```

Output is: `2,479.36`

Comment: Boom that was it. Thank you so much. And thank you for not being so negative. I checked the manual and I could not figure it out. We are here to get help right? This was a legit question but people belittle you "Check the Manual" - Whatever Mr. Smarty Pants who assumes I am lazy. Anyway... that was it. Thanks so much.

Comment: I agree, you asked a well formatted question with problem explained and examples provided

Comment: Use it with for example 12, 12.00 comes out. Not good. it should be 12,00 €